# Detailed Balance for Hamiltonian Monte Carlo

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, markov-process

I am trying to understand the detailed balance proof present in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/9208011v2 (page 4).

**My question:** Why do we consider the volume of a neighborhood of points for HMC detailed balance instead of work with a single point? What function does $\delta V$ have?

Proof reproduced here (where $p$ is the canonical distribution and $a$ is the acceptance probability):

To see that detailed balance holds, consider a small region of volume δV around the point $A = (q_A, p_A)$. Suppose that a forward trajectory from A leads to the
point $B = (q_B, p_B)$. The other points in the region around A will lead to a region
around B, which will also have volume $\delta V$ , since the leapfrog method preserves
phase space volume. Due to time reversibility, a backward trajectory from $B$ will
lead to $A$. The detailed balance condition with respect to the regions around $A$ and
$B$ can now be written as
$$p(q_A, p_A) \delta V \frac{1}{2}
· a(H(q_B, p_B)−H(q_A, p_A))
= p(q_B, p_B) \delta V \frac{1}{2} a(H(q_A, p_A)−H(q_B, p_B))$$
The left side of the above equation is the probability of moving from the region
around $A$ to the region around $B$. The first factor is the Boltzmann probability for
being in the region around A at the start, the second factor ($\frac{1}{2}$) is the probability of
selecting a forward direction for the trajectory, and the third factor is the probability
that this trajectory will be accepted. The right side expresses the probability of
moving from the region around B to the region around A in analogous fashion.

Comment: Can you make your question more explicit? It is not clear to me what exactly it is you're wondering about.

Comment: @Forgottenscience I've edited to hopefully make it more clear. I'm just not sure why we need to consider a neighborhood of points instead of work with a single point.